# How to give pull request to a github private repository which is now public

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I am working in a project hosted in GitHub which was private. I forked it and contributed in it by raising pull request.

Now that private project is public. My forked repository was locked up for a while which I fixed by making it public([more info here](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/#changing-a-private-repository-to-a-public-repository)).

The problem is: Now I don't see the message `forked from some_repository`.

Because of this, I can not give pull request to that parent repository.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a private repository is made public, each of its **private forks** is
>   turned into **a standalone private repository** and becomes the parent of
>   its own new repository network.

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/#changing-a-private-repository-to-a-public-repository

My solution:

(1) Fork from original repository

(2) Use compare and merge software (for example [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) or [Beyond Compare 4](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php)) then merge to your folk.

(3) Send pull request from your fork to parent repository, then merge code.

(4) Delete your own (parent) repository